# Are there any religions out there where skeptics are treated better than believers of a wrong religion (by God)?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, pascal

It is a fact that most, if not all religious people view their religion as full of reward.  This commonly takes the form of an after life, or even supposed "blessings" in this life.  I'm looking for any religion that doesn't lump together all nonbelievers (whether they don't believe in that specific God or don't believe in any of them at all) for purposes of reward/punishment.  I know some religions don't reward based upon belief, but by action.  However, I wouldn't view this as treating an atheist as any different than a believer of another religion - as both are held to the same type of standard for their actions.

My reason for asking involves Pascal's wager.  I apologize as this might be viewed as off topic without further clarification.  There's, however, no religion board for questions about general religion though on stack exchange.  The question I think has philosophical implications though.

Comment: Assuming from your name and terminology that you're coming from a Christian context, you may find some comfort in *The Catechism of the Catholic Church*,  845-856, especially 846-847. 
I would also suggest reading part or all of Pascal's [*Pensées*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/18269/18269-h/18269-h.htm) sections 1-4 (it's only about 80 pages). Pascal is much smarter, more honest, and less wrong in context than the typical bit of ill-founded game theory that's usually called Pascal's Wager gives him credit for.

Comment: thanks for that @gs game theory and religion is pretty weird and slightly scary. personally, i've been trying to game it by allowing for "God" but the mere possibility of His "existence" hah

Comment: @g s I'm not coming from a Christian context.  I'm a de facto atheist.  My work is a little complex.  I'll post a link to it when it is available in August.  Basically, I hold that the probability that God exists is zero, yet it is still possible that God exists.  One reason to hold such a view is for the sceptic to respond to Pascal's wager.  I'm trying to have Pascal's wager pigeonhole the atheist into taking the probability that God exists as zero.  Before you object, one can have a probability 0 event that can happen.  One just needs infinite sets for this to happen.  I agree about Pascal.

Comment: I should say I agree about Pascal except for one error he made.  He thought that probability zero events can't happen.  Through the work of George Cantor, we now know that he was wrong.

Comment: that sounds fun @PaulBurchett can you tag me when it's done

Comment: @doot_s I definitely will.  Thanks for the interest!

Comment: Removed ref to Vedic hymn

Comment: Try to remember that doing math with infinitesimals and limits-as-tend-to-infinities is fairly advanced calculus, and large numbers of concatenated probabilities are extremely sensitive to approximation mistakes. If you're trying to do arithmetic with infinities and/or concatenate huge numbers of approximated probabilities, you're opening yourself to catastrophic errors of reasoning.

Comment: E.G. "There are an infinite number of possible reasons why one could not make it to work in the morning. An infinite chain of x_n where each x_n is less than 1 by some finite value multiplies together to 0, therefore nobody has ever gone to work ever."

Comment: @g s Yes, one does have to be careful when working with infinities, whether infinitely big or small.

Comment: I don't believe it is the case that most religions believe their adherents are so much better off. In fact, I can't think of any except Islam and certain strains of Protestantism that make a big deal out of that.